# How to focus a styled component?

Tags: styled-components

I have a styled component:

```
const StyledComponent = styled.div`
    ...
`;
```

and I want to `focus` it when the component that uses it is mounted:

```
class someComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.sc.focus();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <StyledComponent innerRef={(elem) => { this.sc = elem; }}>
                ...
            </StyledComponent>
        );
    }
}
```

this technique does not work - is there a solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried using the `tabindex={0}` attribute in your StyledComponent?

Comment: @vinhas that didn't work for me, setting `tabIndex="0"` on the component as a jsx attribute did work

Answer (score 2):

You can't focus non-interactive elements without the use of [`tabIndex` ("tabindex" in normal HTML)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex). The "div" element is considered non-interactive (unlike anchor links "a" and button controls "button".)

If you want to be able to focus this element, you'll need to add a tabIndex prop. You can use [`.attrs`](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#attrs) if desired to have it be added automatically so you don't need to write the prop every time.

Comment: `.attrs` refuses to add it also :-(

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/master/docs/tips-and-tricks.md#refs-to-dom-nodes)
 has an example with both React 16 `React.createRef()` and the callback method.

Have you tried setting the `autoFocus` attribute, or is that not fit for your use case?

Comment: styled-components loses autoFocus for me 

Answer (score -1):

Try passing the `autoFocus` prop to your `StyledComponent` like `<StyledComponent autoFocus />`.